# 401 when sending an activity in response to first Event Message

Tags: botframework

v4.2 SDK c#
When the user initially starts a web chat the html client is sending an Event message. The bot gets the initial event and sends and "processing..." message activity. This is causing a 401 from the directline call. The Bot then proceeds to successfully reply to the Event and then also successfully sends a "sorry there was a problem message" message activity. Looking at the conversation IDs and directline URLs everything looks the same so I don't understand why the initial message is getting a 401. Is there some rule that states that an Event must be processing in silence until the reply is sent? Is there some issue that the HTML client is blocking responses while waiting for the reply?

Comment: It it possible that the backing App Service just...doesn't wake up fast enough to process the initial send activity?

Comment: Please upgrade to v4.3.n  A token refresh bug that would periodically throw a 401 was fixed in January.

Answer (score 0):

V4.2 contains a Token Refresh bug.  If a bot does not receive a message for a certain period, the next message received will fail to send due to an attempt to use an expired token.  This issue has been fixed in V4.3.n  Please upgrade to the latest Bot Builder V4 SDK.